# Check if multiple rows exist in Laravel pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, pivot-table

I can run the following code to check if a single row exists in a pivot table

```
 if($person->comments()->where('comment_id', 1)->exists()) == 1){
   //Do something
 }
```

But how would I check if a list of rows exist?

In simple terms, I want to say 'if the pivot table has rows with comment_ids with id's of 1,2,3,4,5'.

This is what i've got so far.

```
  if(($person->comments()->where('comment_id', 1)->where('comment_id', 2)->where('comment_id', 3)->where('comment_id', 4)->where('comment_id', 5)->exists()) == 1){
     //Do something
  }
```

Comment: Yes, `if(($person->comments()->where('comment_id', 1)->exists()) == 1 && ($person->comments()->where('comment_id', 2)->exists()) == 1 && ($person->comments()->where('comment_id', 3)->exists()) == 1 && ($person->comments()->where('comment_id', 4)->exists()) == 1 && ($person->comments()->where('comment_id', 5)->exists()) == 1){` works, but isn't there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: `if($person->comments()->where('comment_id', 1)->exists()) == 1)` has 4 `(` and 5 `)` (the numbers don't match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count how many there are e.g.:

```
$lookFor = [1,2,3,4];

if($person->comments()->whereIn('comment_id', $lookFor)->count() == count($lookFor)) { 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match `all` id with `and` query then you could do this-

```
$query = $person->comments();
foreach($ids as $id){
    $query->where('comment_id',$id);
}
if(($query->exists()){
 //Do something
}
```

Comment: you want to match all id?? with and query??

Comment: I want to check if multiple rows exist for an id in a single query